# rich:popupPanel hide resets scrollbars

Tags: richfaces

I have a calender like view with a vertical scrollbar. As soon as a location is clicked I show a popupPanel where the data for the calendar entry can be entered. As soon as the hide() of the popupPanel is called the scrollbar of the main view is reset to the top. Why?

I now store the scrollTop before opening the popupPanel and restore it after closing but that is not beautiful because the scrollbar flickers that way.

Does anybody have a suggestion on why the scrollbar position is touched by hiding the popupPanel?

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
>

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <a4j:log id="log" level="INFO" mode="popup" hotkey="M"/> <!-- Ctrl+Shift+M -->

    <h:form id="formId">
        Click anywhere in the div to show the popup...
        <rich:popupPanel id="popupTest" width="200" height="150" modal="true">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Popup panel test
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="controls">
                <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popupTest')}.hide(); return false;">X</h:outputLink>
            </f:facet>
            And here some text...<br/>
            <a href="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popupTest')}.hide(); return false;">Hide popup 1</a><br/>
            <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popupTest')}.hide(); return false;">Hide popup 2</h:outputLink><br/>
            <a href="#" onclick="console.log('click...');">Console message</a><br/>
        </rich:popupPanel>
        <div style="height:2000px; width:100px; border:1px solid green; background:grey;" onclick="#{rich:component('popupTest')}.show()"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Seems that any event handling by the browser resets the scrollbars. Does not have much to do with richfaces... But how to handle the event including the submission of values in the popup and still not reset the scrollbars. Adding 'return false' to the onclick won't be possible...

Thanks,
Milo van der Zee

Richfaces-4.1, MyFaces-2.1.6

Comment: My example did not have much to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it was something strange (for me at least). The popupPanel was not contained in the same div as the content with the scrollbar. Strange enough that resulted in resetting the scrollbar as soon as the popup was closed.

As soon as I added a containing div with position absolute spanning the complete page (left,right,top,bottom all set to 0) the scrollbar of the other div was untouched :)

I can think of that the popup creates a div and then removes it again. Could be that the browser is then forced to render parts of the screen that don't need to be rendered. Just guessing...

MAG,
Milo